# How would you do recreate macOS Catalina page scroll effect

Tags: html, css

https://www.apple.com/macos/catalina/

If you go to this page on a desktop-size viewport, you'll see that as you scroll down, it has the effect of zooming out of a computer screen. How does one do this? Is this simply some parallax effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this effect you will have to use JavaScript or JQuery, check the link it has the same effect on first rest I will leave it to your creativity, [GSAP AND SCROLL MAGIC](https://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_tweening.html)

Comment: What was wrong in my answer that you have to down vote it?